# How do I center the image in the column?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So, I'm trying to create this container that has an image to the left, a title and a description in the middle and a button on the right, but I can't seem to center the image in the first column or the button in the last column, why is that?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <div class="container m-5 mx-auto"  style="background-color: gray;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img class="rounded mt-10" style="height: 75px;" src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/otjbibjaAbiifyN9uVaZyL.jpg" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h5 class="card-title mt-2">Title</h5>
                    <p>Description</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Have you written any custom CSS?

Answer (score -1):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <div class="container m-5 mx-auto"  style="background-color: gray;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align:center">
                    <img class="rounded mt-10" style="height: 75px;" src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/otjbibjaAbiifyN9uVaZyL.jpg" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h5 class="card-title mt-2">Title</h5>
                    <p>Description</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

You can simply add text-align: center

Answer (score -1):

See below snippet for a flex solution.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.col-md-2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.col-md-8 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <div class="container m-5 mx-auto"  style="background-color: gray;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img class="rounded mt-10" style="height: 75px;" src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/otjbibjaAbiifyN9uVaZyL.jpg" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h5 class="card-title mt-2">Title</h5>
                    <p>Description</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```